# Wordpress the_title() giving different ASCII hyphen than the one in database?

Tags: php, wordpress

I discovered this by pure accident upon noticing that something was wrong with my queries. It seems that Wordpress echoes out hyphens with ASCII code of 8211 and the one stored in database have an ASCII code of 45.

This was causing a problem for me because my site enables the visitor to "click-save" a post title in their session/meta and later on it runs it by the database to see what type of post it is, and it kept finding nothing in the DB.

Does anyone know the reason for this? And how I could parse the string to replace the 8211 hyphen with the 45 one on the_title()?

Comment: Wouldn't a better solution be to "click-save" the post ID rather than the post title? That won't change, and the query will be faster, too. (Also, do you have any relevant plugins installed? I don't know WordPress's default behaviour with hyphens, but I know that things like the WP Typography plugin will filter titles and body text to output nicer dashes, etc.)

Comment: That is true, but this is a pretty huge site and it's built this way from the start so it's a bit late for changing that now...

Comment: Well, it's your site. But I still don't think it sounds like it would be that big a change :) Looking around, it's likely that this is the result of the wptexturize filter being run automatically on the title -- see [this anwer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash) on the WordPress Stack Exchange site. I'd guess you'd want `remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );`. Bear in mind that this would probably still leave you open to problems if any future plugins or themes you use start filtering the title.

Comment: Cool. I've fleshed out my comment into an actual answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, WordPress filters the title and body of all posts through [`wptexturize`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wptexturize). Among other typographical niceties, this transforms various sequences of standard ASCII hyphens into appropriate dashes, e.g. " -- " is transformed into an [em-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash#Em_dash).

`wptexturize` is run by WordPress through the filters [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) and [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content). You can remove it -- code adapted from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60379/how-to-prevent-automatic-conversion-of-dashes-to-ndash) -- by, for example:

```
remove_filter( 'the_title', 'wptexturize' );
```

...in your theme's `functions.php`, say, or from within plugin code.

However, I'd suggest that this will (a) make your titles not look as nice (you'll lose smart quotes, nice dashes, etc.), and (b) not be very future-proof. If something else starts filtering your titles -- a new plugin, a different theme -- then you'll be back with database mismatches.

My approach would therefore be to adjust your existing code to use the post ID rather than the title. That's an integer, will never change, is never filtered, and will be faster to look up in the database (not just because it's an integer, but also because there's a unique index on it.)